# Entity Framework 'Bulk' Find

Tags: entity-framework

Suppose I have an order item table:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderItem
(
    orderId INT,
    orderItemId INT,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT orderItem_pk PRIMARY KEY (orderId, orderItemId));
```

In my `dbContext`, I have a corresponding `OrderItem` entity.

Now, in my application I have a collection of detached `OrderItem` entities:

```
var orderItems = new List<OrderItem>(){...};
```

I'd like to determine which of these `orderItems` already exists in the database. How can I check this with one trip to the database? Note, that the entity's key is composite.

(My ultimate goal is to 'upsert' the `orderItems`.)

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
var orderItems = new List<OrderItem>(){...};
var inDatabase = db.Orders.Where(o => orderItems.Contains(o.OrderId)).ToList();
```

`Contains` will be translated to `IN` statement and that list (orderItems) would be attached to your query resulting in only 1 trip to the database.

For the composite to work, you could try something like this

```
var orderItems = new List<OrderItem>(){...};
var result=
       from a in orderItems 
       join b in db.Orders on new { a.field1, a.field2 } equals new { b.field1, b.field2 }
       select new { B = b };
```

Comment: As I pointed out in my question, my key is composite; in other words, a lookup requires checking against `orderId` as well as `orderItemId`.

Comment: Then you'll need to make a join between your local list and the database... but I am not sure if that is going to be too slow..

Comment: AFAIK, you can't join to a local collection.